# How do I take a power set product and find 5 elements such that the intersection between them is an empty set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is the problem:

List 5 elements of this set:

${\{(X, Y)\}\in\\} \mathcal {P}\{1,2,3\} \times \mathcal{P}\{1,2,3\}:X\cap Y= \emptyset\ \}$

I know that: $${\mathcal{P }(\{1,2,3\}= {\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}}}$$

Does this involve taking massive Cartesian products? The intersection between two sets is disjoint when they have no other like elements, but I don't get how to find the intersection between the product of power sets as an empty set or disjoint?

Comment: $|A\times B| = |A|\times |B|$ regardless of how complicated or simple of sets $A,B$ happen to be, so you have $|\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})\times \mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})| = 2^3\times 2^3 = 64$.  That is not entirely relevant here though...

Comment: $(\varnothing,\{1,2,3\})$ and $(\{1,2\},\{3\})$ are both elements of the set. Do see why? Can you add $3$ pairs yourself? Then you are ready.

Comment: You just want to list out five ordered pairs where each entry in the ordered pair is itself a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ and their intersection is empty... Here are two to get you started:  $(\{1\},\{2\}), (\{1,2\},\{3\})$

Comment: Now... as for the question of how large your set in question actually is, for each of $1,2,3$ choose whether it appears in the set on the left exclusively, appears in the set on the right exclusively, or does not appear at all.  Applying multiplication principle you'll find that there are $3^3 = 27$ valid ordered pairs in your set.  You were only tasked with listing five.

Comment: [Here is another similar example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041955/determining-the-list-elements-of-u-a-b-in-mathcal-px-%c3%97-mathcal-px-mi?rq=1) with a slightly different condition.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So this is like a subset within a subset of ordered pairs and they can be any combination of the product of the power sets? so ({1,2,3}, {}),({1,2,3}, {1}), ({1,2,3}, {2}), ({1,2,3}, {3}) for example would be four valid elements where the intersection is empty?

Comment: Not quite: the intersection of$\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1\}$ is $\{1\}$. The set contains for example $\{1,2\},\{3\})$, $(\{1\},\{2\})$, $(\{1\},\{3\})$ or $(\{1\},\{2,3\})$.